# Android app which detects snoring/sleep apnea

Tags: android, audio

Android app which detects snoring or sleep anomalies by recording audio (it doesn't need to analyze it itself). I tried the `haven` app, but it doesn't work on Android 13.

Answer (score 1):

**Sleep as Android** by Petr Nálevka claims to detect snoring (which is associated with obstructive sleep apnea).

I have personally used **Sleep as Android**, and it is quite good.  I have not, however, used the specific feature to detect snoring.  If I recall correctly, it is so advanced that you can sync it with another device to filter out snoring from a bed partner.

The official website is:

- https://sleep.urbandroid.org

The link to the app on Google's Play store is:

- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.urbandroid.sleep

The link to the paid unlocker on Google's Play store is:

- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.urbandroid.sleep.full.key

The paid unlocker unlocks additional features.  I don't know if the paid unlocker is needed for the snore detection feature.

One of the many things I like about **Sleep as Android** is that the developer(s) is/are constantly improving it.  Updates are frequent (once or twice per month) and add new functionality plus fix known bugs.

I have personally recommended **Sleep as Android** to quite a few people, and I've never heard a complaint.  Everyone seems to like it.